# turtle.Screen().screensize() not outputting the right screensize

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have written some code to place dots all around the screen randomly; however, it does not cover the entire screen:

```
import turtle
import random

t = turtle.Turtle()

color = ["red", "green", "blue", "pink", "yellow", "purple"]
t.speed(-1)
for i in range(0, 500):
    print(turtle.Screen().screensize())
    z = turtle.Screen().screensize()
    x = z[0]
    y = z[1]
    t.color(color[random.randint(0,5)])
    t.dot(4)
    t.setposition(random.randint(-x,x), random.randint(-y,y))


turtle.done()
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WUap.jpg)

Comment: `.screensize()` isn't quite what you want here - it works with the size that the display widget *wants* to be, but normally it's constrained to fill the window, so the window's actual size overrides it.  Use `.window_width()`, `.window_height` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Screen" refers to the turtle's logical boundaries (scrollable area) which may not be the same as the window size.

Call [`Screen().setup(width, height)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.setup) to set your window size, then use the [`Screen().window_width()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.window_height) and `Screen().window_height()` functions to access its size.

You could also make sure the `screensize` matches the window size, then use it as you are doing. Set the screen size with [`Screen().screensize(width, height)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.screensize).

Additionally, your random number selection is out of bounds. Use

```
random.randint(0, width) - width // 2
```

to shift the range to be centered on 0.

Putting it together:

```py
from random import choice, randint
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


screen = Screen()
screen.setup(480, 320)
colors = "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "yellow", "purple",
t = Turtle()
t.speed("fastest")

for _ in range(0, 100):
    t.color(choice(colors))
    t.dot(4)
    w = screen.window_width()
    h = screen.window_height()
    t.setposition(randint(0, w) - w // 2, randint(0, h) - h // 2)

screen.exitonclick()
```