# What is the size of the Python Turtle window in pixels?

Tags: python, window, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I used the function screensize() and it told me that my window was (400, 300). I need to get to the top left hand corner to draw some stuff, but when I put in (-400, 300), my turtle goes way off the window. Is there any other function I can use to get the size of my turtle window?

Comment: I think by default, the screen center is (0,0). The top left corner is (-200, 150). At `x = -400` the turtle is 200 pixels left of the screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [screensize of turtle in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857693/screensize-of-turtle-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The point 0, 0 is in the center of the screen, so if you want to go to the top left corner, you need to use turtle.goto(200, 150). A problem also could be that if you used setup() to create the window, screensize() will return the default, which is (400, 300), even if you screen is bigger.